# Spring or Tomcat: change an HTTP request to HTTPS request

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm using Jasperreport to build a report. I want to include a map, and I realize that the URL used to paint the map is HTTP:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.31567,-8.359737&size=530x270&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap&format=png8&scale=1&markers=label:A%7C43.31567,-8.359737&markers=label:A%7C43.31567,-8.359737&sensor=false&language=es
```

I go through the library code and my surprise is that this URL is fixed, you can't stablish if you want to use HTTP or HTTPS.

So, I think that my only solution is to try to map this URL to HTTPS.

Is it possible to specify it in Spring or Tomcat? In such a way that the real URL was:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.31567,-8.359737&size=530x270&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap&format=png8&scale=1&markers=label:A%7C43.31567,-8.359737&markers=label:A%7C43.31567,-8.359737&sensor=false&language=es
```

Thanks!

Comment: This article may help you: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/richardtiffin/archive/2010/10/15/applying-ssl-to-a-spring-web-application-on-tomcat.aspx

Comment: I can't access this website, I always get a connection timeout... Thank!

Comment: What do you want exactly that Spring or Tomcat do ? I could not understand you requirement ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I want that all the requests to http://maps.google.com/ be mapped to https://maps.google.com, cause we have the needed to use HTTPS instead of HTTP, and Jasperreports has not any configuration to do that.

Comment: @sp00m please, can you resume me what this page says? I can't access and it's important for me... Thank you very much!